# Why is assignment bad practice in functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

I just wonder, why assignment is not considered good practice in functional programming. It would not hurt to make assignments as long it is in the function. The function would still be pure.

Why else is it not good practice to use assignment in functional programming?

Comment: Because it makes refactoring harder. You can no longer move code around while only making sure that the variables you depend on are in scope, you now also have to think about stateful behaviour again. It just isn't functional programming any more. Sure, you can implement pure functions in imperative style and use them elsewhere in functional programs, but that doesn't make the code with assignments any less imperative.